# Remote debugging on different archs

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

Is it possible to remotely debug a program on a PPC target machine (obsiously by gdbserver) with a x86 version of gdb or there is need to build a cross-gdb?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to debug a PPC target with a GDB running on x86 host; and yes, you need a cross-gdb for doing that.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean to say the x86 host will need a cross-gdb in order to connect and correctly interface with the gdbserver running on the PPC target?